# How can I execute a Node.js command from an Angular .NET C# app on a remote web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npm

Is it possible to have a C#, ASP.NET Core, and Angular web site execute a Node.js command (i.e., `npm list`) when I click a button on the form, and capture the results into a variable?  The solution needs to work on a remote web server too, not just localhost.

Here's a complete Angular application that illustrates what I need.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'read-angular-packages';
  
  //This line of hard corded values works but I how can I dynamically populate the array with installed Angular packages?
  packages = ['Test package 1', 'Test package 2', 'Test package 3'];  
 //The next line is pseudo code. How can I execute this npm command and store its results into the packages array?
 //packages = npm list -g --depth=0;  
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<html>
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"></head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <h2>Here is a listing of the Angular packages that are installed on the web server:</h2>
        <br>
        <li *ngFor="let package of packages">
          {{ package }}
        </li>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Does this blog useful to you ?](https://codeburst.io/run-an-external-executable-in-asp-net-core-5c2f8b6cacd9)